# How to do something on delete in Squeryl

Tags: scala, squeryl

I have `A and B(a_id:Long)` entities.

`B` depends on `A`. So I've set `constrainReference(onDelete cascade)`. Everything works fine.

But when I delete `A` I want to free some resources depending on `B`. Can somehow intercept `B`'s `onDelete()` and perform operations then with a Squeryl way or I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Schema try:

```
override def callbacks = Seq(
        afterDelete(table) call (record => logger.debug("afterDelete")))
```